# How do I change my featured page in Joomla! 1.7 to have more than one column?

Tags: joomla

I'm having a problem with my home page in Joomla! 1.7. Everything was fine layout-wise first. I had a three-column set-up, images to the left, main content in the middle, and testimonials to the right. I then added a News Flash menu module to the left position. Subsequently, the footer section shot up to the top of the page and all the rest of the content moved and nested itself to the left. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could have prompted that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in the CSS styling of the template to me.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Sucks.

Comment: If you're prepared to get your hands dirty in the code of the template it probably wouldn't be too hard to fix it.